# Como transformar este Json num ArrayList de objetos?

Tags: java, android, json, array, gson

Estou trabalhando em um projeto em que estou fazendo uma consulta no banco de dados e preciso retornar uma lista de usuários do banco para serem listados em meu aplicativo.

Eu possuo a seguinte linha Json (retornada pelo servidor):

```
{"id": 1, "nome": Raphael, "sexo": M}{"id": 2, "nome": teste, "sexo": M}
```

Código executado no servidor:

```
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    $result .= '{"id": '.$res['account_id'].', "nome": '.$res['nome'].', "sexo": '.$res['sexo']."}";
```

No exemplo eu possuo 2 usuários cadastrados, Raphael e teste, mas quando recebo os dados pelo android não estou conseguindo de maneira alguma transformar isso em um vetor ou um ArrayList de minha classe usuários.

Código da classe:

```
public class TesteUsuarios {
    String nome, sexo;
    int id;

    TesteUsuarios(int id, String nome, String sexo)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }
}
```

Como fazer para uma "consulta multipla" se tornar um TesteUsuarios[] ou um ArrayList ?

**NOTA:** Estou usando o API Gson, e já tentei achar a solução tanto por ele quanto as funções básicas do java.

**NOTA²:** Sugestões para melhorar o código em php, são muito bem vindas também, pois tentei trabalhar com arrays e ele retornava no encode "ArrayArray".

---

**Edit**
O problema foi resolvido com a resposta do ramaral, e uma alteração na parte php do código.

Alteração no php:

```
$result = array(array("id" => 5, "nome" => "Raphael", "sexo" => "M"), array("id" => 6, "nome" => "Teste", "sexo" => "M"));
```

Basicamente gerar o json a partir de uma array multidimensional.

Espero que alguem que esteja tendo o mesmo problema possa se aproveitar desde post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se tem o resultado no formato Json numa string, use para

- desserializar em um *array*:

  ```
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  TesteUsuarios[] usuariosArray = gson.fromJson(jsonString, TesteUsuarios[].class);
  ```
- desserializar em uma *List*:

  ```
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  Type usuariosListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<TesteUsuarios>>(){}.getType(); 
  List<TesteUsuarios> usuariosList = gson.fromJson(jsonString, usuariosListType);
  ```

**Nota:**

Esse seu json para ser considerado como um array tem de começar com `[` e terminar com `]` e cada item ser separado por `,`

```
[{"id": 1, "nome": Raphael, "sexo": M},{"id": 2, "nome": teste, "sexo": M}]
```

Comment: Irei responder seu comentário na postagem principal, mostrando o erro apresentado. Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Desculpa, mas não entendi exatamente como resolver aquele problema, refiz o Json e continua dando erro:

$result = array(array(5, "Raphael", "M"), array(6, "Teste", "M"));

Comment: Eu, em php, não consigo ajudar. Veja na edição da resposta como deve ficar o json.

Comment: Com a sua resposta no tópico principal consegui resolver meu problema, obrigado.